# How to get the pid of external process

Tags: ruby

I ran the external `python` script by `system(run_command)`

But I want to get the pid of the running python script,

So I tried to use `fork` and get the pid,

But the returned pid was the pid of the fork's block, not the python process.

How could I get the pid of the python process, thanks.

[image]

```
arguments=[
"-f #{File.join(@public_path, @streaming_verification.excel.to_s)}",
"-duration 30",
"-output TEST_#{@streaming_verification.id}"
]
cmd = [ "python",
@automation[:bin],
arguments.join(' ')
]
run_command = cmd.join(' ').strip() 

task_pid = fork do 
    system(run_command)
end
```

---

(Update)

I tried to use the spawn method.

The retuned pid was still not the pid of the running python process.

I got the pid 5177 , but the actually pid,I wanted, is 5179

**run.sh**

```
./main.py  -f ../tests/test_setting.xls -o testing_`date +%s` -duration 5
```

**sample.rb**

```
cmd = './run.sh'
pid = Process.spawn(cmd)
print pid
Process.wait(pid)
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

According to [`Kernel#system`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Kernel.html#method-i-system):

> Executes command… **in a subshell**. command… is one of following forms.

You will get pid of subshell, not the command.

---

How about using [`Process#Spwan`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Process.html#method-c-spawn)? It returns the pid of the subprocess.

```
run_command = '...'
pid = Process.spawn(cmd)
Process.wait(pid)
```

Comment: well, i tried your solution, but it didn't work for me. I updated the post with your solution. did i misunderstand your explination ?

Comment: @poc, Ah.. You're running the command through shell. `pid` will the pid of the shell, not the command. You should call the program directly to get the pid of the process.