# Start and Kill the browser using Ruby

Tags: ruby

All,

I've got a problem which I need your help.

Using Ruby 1.9.3 in Windows, I'm starting a browser with the following command:

```
system('start http://www.stackoverflow.com')
```

I've tried getting the pid of the above system cmd in various ways like exec, Thread and IO.popen. But everytime I get the different PID which I assume the PID of the ruby process.

But I need the PID of the started browser, so that I can kill the browser once I finish my task at the end.

Note that I don't want to use Watir / Selenium or any automation tool.

Kindly help me on this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the pid of external process](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21396137/how-to-get-the-pid-of-external-process)

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4366071/popen-getting-pid-of-newly-run-process

Comment: I already had a look at the above links and tried it. But still my problem is not resolved. So I believe it may not be a duplicate of those.

Comment: And both the above questions are not yet answered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use `start`, it will spawn new window, open browser and then detach the window. Specify the browser path explicitly to solve the problem:

```
browser = %q{"C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe"}
pipe = IO.popen("#{browser} http://www.stackoverflow.com")
puts pipe.pid
Process.kill(9, pipe.pid)
```

Run `start /?` for help message of `start` command.

Comment: You are great. I like this.